# Automatically splitting large square table across pages

Tags: tables

I am writing a program that has to generate a PDF. I decided to generate LaTeX source and compile it with `pdflatex`. The problem is that one of printed elements is big square table (up to 97x97). First row and first column are headers that contains short string. Other cells can contain number in range from 0 to 255. The best solution would be to let LaTeX layout the table so my program would just generate data.

I just cannot find a way to scale/rotate/split among pages this table so it remains legible.

Example table I try to fit to page(s):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating,graphics,longtable}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
        \begin{longtable}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                & \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1} \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
                \hline
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT:

Perfect solution for me would be hand-written LaTeX file that contains all formating rules and definitions, and that is included to generated one. Generated one contains only data and essential markup (also from included file).

An algorithm used to split table by LaTeX could be:

1. Assume max number of columns and rows per page (for example 32).
2. Calculate number of pages needed to print table (using assumption from point 1).
3. Try to make equal number of columns/rows on all pages (for example for 90x90 table first split would be 32 columns + 32 columns + 26 columns. This point makes it 30 columns + 30 columns +  30 columns).
4. Print sub-tables in some order (ex. left-right, top-bottom)

It should preserve cell content and formatting (if any).

Is it possible at all? Maybe I should use something else to generate PDF?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is generating two/more tables from one data source an option? Then you would get two separate tables/pages. For first table you need data from the first column plus first half of other columns and for the second table you would need data forming the first column again plus second half of the columns.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm just looking at options I have. Perfect solution for me would be some hand-written LaTeX that would be included to output of my application. Hand-written file would take care of layout and splitting. Generated file would contain only data (and some essential markup).

Answer (score 1):

To get one row in even at landscape orientation you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape,longtable}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\tabcolsep{.9pt}
\tiny

        \begin{longtable}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                & \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1}& \rot{K1} \\
                \hline
                K1 & 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200& 200 \\
        \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

and if you do that the whole table fits on a page.

Whether that's readable depends on your eyesight and whether it's on paper or in a viewer where you can zoom.

If it is not readable you will have to reformat the data as multiple tables but hard to suggest any such split as presumably the real data isn't a row of `200` for which a more compact format would be

```
a row of 200s
```

But given some domain knowledge you can usually split a table somehow.....

Comment: `\begin{longtable}{l|*{64}{c|}}` maybe a good idea :-)

Comment: It fits but font is too small. I can split table in an output of my application but I would prefer not to. I'd like to write whole table and have LaTeX split it. I updated a question with more explanation what I would like to do.